# cannot convert from 'openqa.selenium.by' to 'openqa.selenium.iwebelement'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to perform a mousehover and then click on a submenu that wasn't present

This is my code:

```
private By RMenu = By.LinkText("Reports");

public HomePage SetMenu(string menu)
{
    Actions Rmouseover = new Actions(_driver);
    Rmouseover.MoveToElement(RMenu).Perform();
    return this;
}
```

And I am getting this error at (RMenu) `Rmouseover.MoveToElement(RMenu).Perform()`:

> cannot convert from 'openqa.selenium.by' to
>   'openqa.selenium.iwebelement'

I have tried `Rmouseover.MoveToElement(RMenu).Build().Perform()` and I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong or what am I not doing?

Answer (score 3):

`MoveToElement` receives `IWebElement` as parameter, not `By`.

```
private By RMenu = By.LinkText("Reports");

public HomePage SetMenu(string menu)
{
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(RMenu);
    Actions Rmouseover = new Actions(_driver);
    Rmouseover.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
    return this;
}
```